# maximum screen size in IOS 6.1.2 webview

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cordova, webview

I want to fit my webapp size into my device webview maximum size but i dont know why it scrolls. The webapp oversizes the webview.

The index.html has the following meta tags:

```
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

I am using Lungo 2.2.1 and cordova 3.4.0 in my application. The device i am testing is an Ipad2 with 6.1.2.